# What is the difference between dockerService and DockerServer in the kubelet source code

Tags: kubernetes, container-runtime-interface

When I read the k8s source code, I found that both **dockerService** located in `pkg/kubelet/dockershim/docker_service.go` and **DockerServer** located in `pkg/kubelet/dockershim/remote/docker_server.go` seem to implement the interface of the `CRI shim server`.

But I don't understand the difference between the two, why do I need to distinguish between the two?

> k8s version is tag 1.23.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- DockerServer simply creates **dockershim grpc server**

```
// DockerServer is the grpc server of dockershim.
type DockerServer struct {
    // endpoint is the endpoint to serve on.
    endpoint string
    // service is the docker service which implements runtime and image services.
    service DockerService
    // server is the grpc server.
    server *grpc.Server
}
...
// Start starts the dockershim grpc server.
func (s *DockerServer) Start() error {
    glog.V(2).Infof("Start dockershim grpc server")
    l, err := util.CreateListener(s.endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to listen on %q: %v", s.endpoint, err)
    }
    // Create the grpc server and register runtime and image services.
    s.server = grpc.NewServer()
    runtimeapi.RegisterRuntimeServiceServer(s.server, s.service)
    runtimeapi.RegisterImageServiceServer(s.server, s.service)
    go func() {
        // Use interrupt handler to make sure the server to be stopped properly.
        h := interrupt.New(nil, s.Stop)
        err := h.Run(func() error { return s.server.Serve(l) })
        if err != nil {
            glog.Errorf("Failed to serve connections: %v", err)
        }
    }()
    return nil
}
```

- DockerService is the interface **implement CRI remote service server**

```
// DockerService is the interface implement CRI remote service server.
type DockerService interface {
    runtimeapi.RuntimeServiceServer
    runtimeapi.ImageServiceServer
}

// **dockerService uses dockershim service to implement DockerService**.
```

---

BTW, are you sure you will use in the future? From the latest (5 days ago) news:
[Kubernetes is Moving on From Dockershim: Commitments and Next Steps](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/01/07/kubernetes-is-moving-on-from-dockershim/):

- **Kubernetes is removing dockershim in the upcoming v1.24 release.**
- **If you use Docker Engine as a container runtime for your Kubernetes cluster, get ready to migrate in 1.24**
- **Full removal is targeted in Kubernetes 1.24, in April 2022.**
- **We'll support Kubernetes version 1.23, which includes dockershim, for another year in the Kubernetes project.**

Comment: @Vir Thanks, I'm currently learning k8s so this shouldn't have much impact, this should be seen as an implementation of other CRI shims